# Need to echo variable inside quotations

Tags: php, iframe

i have this piece of code:

```
<?php
    $title = the_title();
    $field['url'] = "<iframe src='http://xxx.xx/embed?t='" . echo $title . "width='640' height='360' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>;"
    ?>
```

And i need the `. echo $title .` but it doesn't work, my site doesn't even load. So is there any other possibility to echo the variable `$title`? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

There is a great function called [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$title = the_title();
$field['url'] = sprintf('<iframe src="http://xxx.xx/embed?t=%s" width="640" height="360" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>;"', $title);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the echo and moving the ; outside of the quotes

```
<?php
$title = the_title();
$field['url'] = "<iframe src='http://xxx.xx/embed?t='" . $title . "width='640' height='360' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' scrolling='no' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
?>
```